How do I improve my model accuracy and val_accuracy for my cnn model?
I'm using 3000+ retinopathy images in my CNN model. The accuracy remains around 77 to 80, how do i improve the accuracy value and reduce loss value?
I've tried dropout and Adam optimizer to increase it to 80 from around 76. Adding more layers seems to overfit the data.
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)
    
    train_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training'
    )

    val_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='validation'
    )
    
    return train_gen, val_gen

# Build the CNN model
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])
type her# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Callbacks
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience = 8)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.keras', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss')

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_gen,
    epochs= 30,
    shuffle=True,  
    validation_data=val_gen,
    callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint]e```

```Epoch 3/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 371ms/step - accuracy: 0.6982 - loss: 0.8874 - val_accuracy: 0.7291 - val_loss: 0.8297
Epoch 4/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 36s 383ms/step - accuracy: 0.7297 - loss: 0.7982 - val_accuracy: 0.6936 - val_loss: 0.8326
Epoch 5/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 36s 384ms/step - accuracy: 0.7318 - loss: 0.7914 - val_accuracy: 0.6908 - val_loss: 0.8419
Epoch 6/30
7102 - val_accuracy: 0.7510 - val_loss: 0.7556
Epoch 10/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 373ms/step - accuracy: 0.7721 - loss: 0.6885 - val_accuracy: 0.7524 - val_loss: 0.7528
Epoch 11/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 376ms/step - accuracy: 0.7743 - loss: 0.6734 - val_accuracy: 0.7442 - val_loss: 0.7768
7102 - val_accuracy: 0.7510 - val_loss: 0.7556
Epoch 10/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 373ms/step - accuracy: 0.7721 - loss: 0.6885 - val_accuracy: 0.7524 - val_loss: 0.7528
Epoch 11/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 376ms/step - accuracy: 0.7743 - loss: 0.6734 - val_accuracy: 0.7442 - val_loss: 0.7768
Epoch 12/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 374ms/step - accuracy: 0.7726 - loss: 0.6500 - val_accuracy: 0.7606 - val_loss: 0.7530
Epoch 13/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 378ms/step - accuracy: 0.7776 - loss: 0.6513 - val_accuracy: 0.7538 - val_loss: 0.8011
Epoch 14/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 36s 382ms/step - accuracy: 0.7981 - loss: 0.5986 - val_accuracy: 0.7456 - val_loss: 0.7928
Epoch 15/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35s 371ms/step - accuracy: 0.8114 - loss: 0.5714 - val_accuracy: 0.7579 - val_loss: 0.8129
Epoch 16/30
92/92 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 36s 384ms/step - accuracy: 0.8061 - loss: 0.5709 - val_accuracy: 0.7524 - val_loss: 0.8745```


Without more context, like simple EDA. It's possible that the data you feed might be garbage that leads the model became GIGO

First off, if you really have to use that sequential model of yours then add a Batch Normalization layer after each MaxPooling layer. Try getting rid of the kernel regularizer, using a lower dropout rate and GlobalAveragePooling instead of Flatten as well. Otherwise just use a well-known model such as the EfficientNet. Start with the EfficientNetB0 and see if it overfits. If it doesn't, then go up the ladder (B1, B2,...).
Second: use some sort of data augmentation. I recommend using the Albumentations framework.
Last but not least, you're using the wrong loss. If you have a softmax output, then you should be using sparse cross-entropy instead of categorical. Categorical cross-entropy means that the outputs are simultaneous (i.e. two different labels can happen at the same time), which is the opposite of what a softmax implies (output is a probability distribution, i.e. the sum of the outputs is equal to 1). If you think that the output labels can happen at the same time and that you should be using categorical cross-entropy, then you should use a sigmoid output instead.

Thanks! changing the loss and adding batch normalization and data augmentation helped in getting the Validation loss down to 55 and val_accuracy to 80. But it remains stuck at those values even beyond 30 epochs.

You can try Batch Normalization.
